# PHP goto alternative

Tags: php, loops

I've just recently started using PHP 5.4 and have noticed as of 5.3 you can use goto to jump to sections of code which I am using to jump from a loop section. My question is after having read this post... [Is GOTO in PHP evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900017/is-goto-in-php-evil) is this bad practice in this case or is it a viable solution?

```
<?php
while ($thisResult = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {      
    if($article && $i > 0) {
        goto comments;
    }

?>
    <h2>
        <a href="/plugins/<?=$thisResult['post_name']?>"><?=$thisResult['post_title']?></a>
        <span><?=$thisResult['post_modified_gmt']?></span>
    </h2>
    <p class="content">
        <?=nl2br($thisResult['post_content']);?>
    </p>
    <br />  
 <?php
    comments: 
        if ($article) {
?>
        <p class="comment"><?=$thisResult['comment_content']?>
<?php
        }

    $i++;
}

 ?>
```

Comment: it's a bad practise and completely unneccessary in your code example

Comment: What would you suggest then?

Comment: mixing logic (retrieve from database) with html output is a bad practice as well. and inserting something into `while` just to output it once does not make sense

Comment: I dont know what ur script should do, but whenever you need to use GOTO it means you wrote your script wrong way... I dont think you can hit that expert code you will need to use GOTO.

Comment: It's because that code also powers a summary of articles so if an article is not specified

Comment: Using PHP short tags instead of the full `<?php` is also bad practice

Answer (score 1):

This is called spaghetti programming and is a bad practice. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code

here is what you can do instead for your code

```
    <?php
    while ($thisResult = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {      
        if($article && $i > 0) {

        }
    else {
    ?>
        <h2>
            <a href="/plugins/<?php $thisResult['post_name']?>"><?php $thisResult['post_title']?></a>
            <span><?php $thisResult['post_modified_gmt']?></span>
        </h2>
        <p class="content">
            <?php nl2br($thisResult['post_content']);?>
        </p>
        <br />  
     <?php
    }
            if ($article) {
    ?>
            <p class="comment"><?php $thisResult['comment_content']?>
    <?php
            }

        $i++;
    }

     ?>
```

A simple else solves it. you can probably find more elegant solutions using switch cases or flags.

The problem is that your code will be hard to edit and add stuff to it.

Comment: Bad practice using short tags and not `<?php`

Comment: I don't see any spaghetti code here. Are you sure you're not just repeating a mantra for the sake of it?

Comment: @DarylGill **nothing** wrong with short tags. please quit that nasty rumor

Comment: @YourCommonSense Acceptable, but They're not recommended

Comment: Why not? is it only about readability? thanks all really appreciate the time to respond and give pointers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i am referring to the goto approach.

Comment: [php short open tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). It will not support since PHP 5.4 and onward.

Comment: @TNK it will stay supported, read carefully. @YourCommonSense `<?php echo` seems to me much more readable

Comment: @TNK from your link: Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is **always** available.

Answer (score 1):

This is rewrite of the same code without using `goto`, to show you that you can always make it without it

```
<?php
    while ($thisResult = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
        if(!$article || $i <= 0): ?>
            <h2>
                <a href="/plugins/<?php echo $thisResult['post_name']; ?>"><?php echo $thisResult['post_title']; ?></a>
                <span><?php echo $thisResult['post_modified_gmt']; ?></span>
            </h2>
            <p class="content">
                <?php echo nl2br($thisResult['post_content']); ?>
            </p>
            <br />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($article): ?>
            <p class="comment"><?php echo $thisResult['comment_content']; ?></p>
        <?php endif;
        $i++;
    endwhile;
```

I used alternative syntax for control structures, and replaced `<?=` with `<?php echo` as it's much more readable to me. Also, other commenters gave you some good suggestions regarding separation of markup and db functions etc, so please give it a thought

Comment: @YourCommonSense I didn't say there is anything wrong with it. But for me is **much** less readable

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hopefully now it's valid