# How to jump from one Function to another in PHP Class

Tags: php, pdo

I have a php script to pipe through a mail,

```
class mailTest
{
    // (some code here)
    private function saveToDb()
    {
        // (some code here)
        $select = $this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_reques WHERE terminal_id = $term AND request_status ='' ");
        $select = $select->fetchAll();
        if (count($select) > 0) {
            echo "Call already Exist (DISCARD)";
        } else {
            $select_tech = $this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_email WHERE terminal_id = $term");
            $select_tech = $select_tech->fetchAll();
            // (some code here)
        }
    }

    private function sendEmail()
    {
        $this->today = time();
        $this->maildate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-5 minutes', $this->today));

        $select = $this->pdo->query("Select * from tbl_reques WHERE maildate >=  '$this->maildate' ");
        // some code here
        mail($this->from_email, $this->subject, $newmsg, $headers);
    }
}
```

The problem is any time the condition is False i.e `echo "Call already Exist (DISCARD)";` The code will not go to the Next Function. i.e the program get halt. 
PLS is there a way that if that condition is not met, the program will JUMP to next function for continuation of execution. Or is it possible to use GOTO statement. 
Pls what is the best way to handle this in PHP.
Thanks

Comment: no, there is no jump, and you should never be using `goto`. if you want a function to terminate early, then have it `return`. and if you want the next function to execute immediately, then call it immediately: `foo(); bar();`

Comment: Returning in the middle of a function is no better than using goto.  I don't know why that terrible pattern has so much traction in so many languages.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple option for this. You can `return` at the point of failure. Which would exit the function at this point and then do whatever is next in the script being ran. Be sure to do the clean up before your return.

```
if(count($select) > 0) {
    echo "Call already Exist (DISCARD)";
    //Clean up if needed
    return; //You could also return the message 
            //or an error code and have another 
            //evaluation based on that.
} else {
    // Or passes
}
```

You could call the next function but this would be a very bad flow in my opinion

```
if(count($select) > 0) {
    echo "Call already Exist (DISCARD)";
    //Clean up if needed
    $this->sendEmail();
} else {
    // Or passes
}
```

The reason this would be bad is if say in the script you have

```
$mailTest = new mailTest();
$mailTest->saveToDb();
$mailTest->sendEmail(); //When the above fails this is called twice.
```

You could likewise throw an exception

```
if(count($select) > 0) {
    echo "Call already Exist (DISCARD)";
    throw new Exception("Call already Exist (DISCARD)");
} else {
    // Or passes
}
```

Now you need to use `try` and `catch`

```
$mailTest = new mailTest();
try {
    $mailTest->saveToDb();

catch (Exception $e){
    //Do something with $e
    //Clean up the failure if needed
}
$mailTest->sendEmail();
```

There is a `finally` block as well which would run in cases where your catch stops the script.

Comment: Thanks nerdlyist ...... I've tried this but seems not to be working too!

Comment: @Steve could you post the script you are running with this?

Comment: @ Nerdlyist, did you mean I should post all the script here? .... The code is about 300 lines

Comment: @Steve I would not say all 300 lines but where you think the flow is not correct and the updates you have made to your class.

Answer (score 0):

PHP in fact has a `GOTO` statement, see http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.goto.php

However, it is considered bad style to use it, or [in the words of @Konamiman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900017/is-goto-in-php-evil)

> Unless you are programming in assembler, GOTO should always be treated the same way as the life vest of the airplanes: it is good to have them available, but if you need to use them it means that you are in big trouble.

You can call a function simply by writing its name followed by brackets. In the case of class functions you apply it to `$this`:

```
$this->sendEmail();
```