# Break out of while and skip the following loops

Tags: php, while-loop

I am looking for an element in multiple while loops, but if the element is found, I don't need to check the following while loops. How can I achieve something like this?

```
while(something) {
    if (this = key) {
        // break this loop and skip the next ones. Otherwise proceed to next. 
    }
}

while(somethingelse) {
    if (this = key) {
        // break this loop and skip the next ones. Otherwise proceed to next. 
    }
}

while(somethingthird) {
    if (this = key) {
        // break this loop and skip the next ones. Otherwise stop looking. 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the dreaded... `goto`! I am taking a shower now.

Answer (score 3):

Use a variable (boolean) that knows if your condition was checked in the previous while, like this:

```
$breakAll = false; //default false
while(something) {
    if (this = key) {
        // break this loop and skip the next ones. Otherwise proceed to next. 
        $breakAll = true; //now break all whiles
    }
}

while(somethingelse && !breakAll) {
    if (this = key) {
        // break this loop and skip the next ones. Otherwise proceed to next. 
        $breakAll = true; //same here
    }
}

while(somethingthird && !breakAll) {
    if (this = key) {
        // break this loop and skip the next ones. Otherwise stop looking. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Refactor the while loops to a function and return when the element is found

```
function doSomething() {
    while(something) {
        if (this == key) {
            return;
        }
    }

    while(somethingelse) {
        if (this == key) {
            return;
        }
    }

    while(somethingthird) {
        if (this == key) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function

```
function findSpecificElement($element)
{
    while ($something) {
       if ($something == $element) {
         return $something;
       }
    } 

    while ($something) {
       if ($something == $element) {
         return $something;
       }
    } 

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More correct to use php operator: continue, see:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Example:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
    if (!($key % 2)) { // skip even members
        continue;
    }
    do_something_odd($value);
}
```

Operator: break; - break the loop
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

```
while(something) {
    if (this == key) {
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`goto` can be used in a situation like this to jump over the `while` loops that should not be run.

```
while(something) {
    if (this = key) {
        goto yourDoom; // Breaks out of loop and goes to label "yourDoom"
    }
}
while(somethingelse) {
    if (this = key) {
        goto yourDoom; // Breaks out of loop and goes to label "yourDoom"
    }
}
while(somethingthird) {
    if (this = key) {
        goto yourDoom; // Breaks out of loop and goes to label "yourDoom"
    }
}
yourDoom: // This is a label that you can go to
// Do something
```

Comment: I would never recommend using goto as it results in hard to follow code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900017/is-goto-in-php-evil

Comment: @Pachonk This is not even close to being hard to follow. `goto` in PHP does not have the same problems as in other languages, such as C, where using it can cause serious problems. It should have been named something different so people don't mistake the two for the same thing.