# Continue or break a specific loop

Tags: php

I have several loops and would like to specify a particular loop when I use the break or continue instruction

In the [PHP doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php), it is written that I can use the number numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of.

```
$i = 0;
while (++$i) {
    switch ($i) {
    case 5:
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
        break 1;  /* Exit only the switch. */
    case 10:
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
        break 2;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

But I'd like something more friendly like this:

```
$i = 0;
loop1: // Label/tag of loop1
while (++$i) {
    loop2: // Label/tag of loop2
    switch ($i) {
    case 5:
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
        break loop2;  /* Exit only the switch. */
    case 10:
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
        break loop1;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I would recommend instead of break use goto statement to jump in your code Up Or Down that would be much easier.

Comment: Don't use `goto`! [Here is why!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900017/is-goto-in-php-evil)

Comment: you could use not recommended goto [http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.goto.php] (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7), using a label (loopend:) at the end of your while loop.

Comment: @ElasticLamb Label stuff is as mush same as goto thing please look into it in detail you will get my point why i said goto

Comment: **Never** use `goto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Furthermore, too many `break`-Statements can make your code very unreadable and hard to understand. You should restructure your code to avoid `breaks` and use other [control flow statements](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).

```
do {
    $i += 1;
    if($i === 5) {
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
    } else if ($i === 10) {
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
    }
} while($i < 10);
```

You can also try to split your code up in different functions or methods.

```
function doSomething($i) {
    if($i === 5) {
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
    } else if ($i === 10) {
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
    }
}

function run() {
    $i = 0;
    while($i < 10) doSomething(++$i);    
}
```

In the second case you have to be aware of the strong dependency between the two functions. If you would change `run()` so that it counts to 15 the function `doSomething` would misbehave if `$i = 10`. Therefore you should encapsulate them in a class or try to introduce another variable which both functions can use to determine when the loop will end. That will avoid future mistakes and magic things to happen.

```
function doSomething($i, $max) {
    if($i === 5) {
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
    } else if ($i === $max) {
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
    }
}

function run($max) {
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $max) doSomething(++$i);    
}
```

Of course it is no problem to use one, two or even more `breaks` if your code remains readable. But you should consider if there are other more elegant ways to solve your problem. And mostly there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

My personal recommendation is extract nested loop code into the separate methods and/or use the exceptions. In general "break to label" feels like "goto". I don't want you to be eaten by dinosaur ;)

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible, but if you break down your code and put the nested loops in a function you can use `return` to quit all loops. That might improve readability.