# PHP: Valid Reason To Use Goto?

Tags: php

I know that the goto statement is frowned upon but I wanted to know if the following situation would make it the most acceptable.

I want to create a unique random number for a column value but to do that I need to create a random number and check to see if it exists in a table.

```
a:
$rnumber = rand(1, 10);
$queryresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT uniquerandomcolumn FROM tbldata WHERE uniquerandomcolumn =" . $rnumber);

if ($queryresult->num_rows > 0) //if random number exists a row would be returned
{goto a;}  //try again
else {//insert into table}
```

Comment: [What are the valid use cases of goto in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843551/what-are-the-valid-use-cases-of-goto-in-php)

Comment: In your case, you can use a while instead.

Comment: See: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: Is this a general question or specific to this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need goto for that.

```
do
{
    $rnumber = rand(1, 10);
    $queryresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT uniquerandomcolumn FROM tbldata WHERE uniquerandomcolumn =" . $rnumber);
}
while($queryresult->num_rows > 0);
//insert into table}
```

EDIT: This answer is just to prove that goto isn't necessary in the original code. In this particular example, I would advise against using this code and use WereWolf - The Alpha's answer in your code.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the clarification, now I know to use a loop.  The do, while example here seems to be what I'm looking for.  Keep looping until the random number isn't found in the db table.

Comment: @Ralph this is working but a bit dangerous (the loop may run a lot for nothing) - you may want to try *randomly* all 10 numbers, *never* twice the same number, and *only* 10, not more (see my solution below).

Comment: I know what you would tell me.But I think its not correct because the code -Ralph- posted needs to check else but this is not checking that. (check my answer for that please).

Comment: There is no need for the else. All code under the while will happen once a random number has been selected which is not in use. It does the same thing as the else.

Comment: +1 to -ring0- yes I strongly recommend you to prevent that and also I suggest to first store the list of all records in array and check it with rands.

Answer (score 6):

Use this instead, so the number will be unique

```
$id = uniqid(rand(), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead, you should use a while loop, that counts retry attempts:

```
$attempt = 0; $success = false;
while ($attempt++ < 3) {
    // ... make sure $success gets marked true!
    // in case of success, make sure you break here!
}
if (!$success) {
    // Failure
}
```

This makes sure your script never freezes (infinite loop).

Comment: `do` loops only make sense when performing a condition based on something within the block, I think. In this case it'd be quite unnecessary.

Comment: That describes this situation pretty exactly.... *do* a query, if it doesn't produce results, do it again.

Answer (score 0):

The *goto* statement was mainly - if any - used for *error* processing: in a long list of statement, each of them being able to trigger an error, a jump (goto) was made near the bottom of the function to skip all the remaining statements, and run a common error processor at the end of the function.

But nowadays, even PHP has *exception handling*, thus the use of *goto* is even less justified.

**Fix the problem as mentioned**

In your case, you can implement a simple algorithm to perform the equivalent function

```
do {
  $rnumber = rand(1, 10);
  $queryresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT uniquerandomcolumn FROM tbldata WHERE uniquerandomcolumn =" . $rnumber);

} while ($queryresult->num_rows > 0);
```

having the risk of being in an infinite (or very long) loop...

**Room for improvement**

Since the number of tries is limited (1 .. 10), it would be better to

- try all numbers from 1 to 10 (maximum) once *without* repetition
- randomly (eg 7 2 3 9 ...)

ie, perform a *maximum* of 10 tries, and exit if the *row* does not exist or if all 10 tries have been done. To try randomly from 1 to 10, use the [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function to shuffle randomly an array of 1 to 10 elements.

```
$tries = array();
for ($i=1 ; $i<=10 ; $i++) $tries[] = $i; // create an array (1,2,3,4,5...)

shuffle ($tries); // shuffle the array, eg now $tries is (8,2,9,1,7...)

$index = 0; // start with first element of $tries
do {
  $rnumber = $tries[$index++];
  $queryresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT uniquerandomcolumn FROM tbldata WHERE uniquerandomcolumn =" . $rnumber);

} while ($queryresult->num_rows > 0 && $tries < 10);
```

This way you try randomly all 10 possible values, not more.

After the *while* add

```
if ($queryresult->num_rows < 1) {
  // found a non existing number: $tries[$index-1]
}
else {
  // all 10 numbers exist in the DB...
}
```

to deal with the two conditions.

Answer (score -1):

`goto` isn't a good coding practice, it will make your code unaccountable and unmanageable. Don't ever use `goto`. Or else a velociraptor will hit you while you compiling your code.

[image]

> But it's okay if you are making a console application, it's okay.